# Equivalent for Windows messages (EM_LINEFROMCHAR/EM_LINEINDEX) in OSX/Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, nstextview

ALL,

Is there an equivalent for EM_LINEFROMCHAR/EM_LINEINDEX Windows notification in OSX/Cocoa? I couldn't find anything looking [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nstextview).

Basically I'm looking to give a position and receive (x,y) coordinate inside the view.

Answer (score 0):

See `- (CGPoint)locationForGlyphAtIndex:(NSUInteger)glyphIndex;` of `NSLayoutManager`.

You may wanna read on the relation between `NSTextView`, `NSTextStorage` and `NSLayoutManager`.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/nslayoutmanager/1403239-locationforglyphatindex?language=objc